# How to name plants and animals?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I find out by naming plants you can gain money how can I do that.

I'm on PC

Comment: Just to clear it up, you get money for uploading, not renaming.

Comment: Just to clear it up, you get units for "uploading" which can be done offline -   Edit: the game will actually upload them when it goes online, but you get your credits as soon as you perfom the action even if you decide to never go online.

Answer (score 5):

There are two options, rename and upload, or just upload. You can only rename things if you **haven't** already uploaded your discoveries.

To rename something simply hover the planet/system/etc. and press whichever button it prompts on the overlay. I'm not in game and don't know which button it is off hand.

Comment: iirc rename and upload: x; just upload: e

Comment: Square to Upload and Triangle to Rename and Upload on PS4!

Comment: It is important to know that you can only rename it ONCE. If you made a typo or later in the game if you want to use something like a naming scheme you can't rename it again! Uploaded = Name is fixed forever. At least with the actual Next-Update 1.53 (would be great, if we could change our mind later...)

Answer (score 4):

**Discovering**

When you land on a planet that has not yet been discovered, you will automatically discover it, and it will be added to your journal. Other items need to be discovered manually:

**Waypoints/Outposts:** These have a pylon at each site that you need to activate before you are classified as discovering the area.

**Flora/Fauna:** You must scan the object before it is discovered. To do this, you first need the Analysis module installed into your Multitool (it's there by default on your first, but upgrades may not have it by default).

Once you have it installed, you need to bring up the display (<kbd>F</kbd> by default, Right-Click to zoom) and hover over the creature/plant for a few seconds. It will then come up with Analysing. Once it has completed (you need to keep the item in view until it does), you will have discovered it.

[image: Scanner View]

For Fauna, it's worth noting that underneath each animal you can see, there is a green or red dot. If it's red, its a species/sub-species that you have not yet discovered. This can be really handy for attempting to complete the set on a particular planet.

---

**Uploading**

All Discoveries are visible within your "Journal" (<kbd>P</kbd> by default on PC), when you open this, you will see a list of planets and systems on the left hand side.

[image: Journal View]

When you click on a planet, it will load up the data for that planet on the right hand pane. For both planets/systems (on the left), and waypoints, flora and fauna (on the right), discoveries still to be uploaded will be shown with a red icon on the top right of the image.

To upload these, you simply need to press (and hold) <kbd>E</kbd> by default. If you want to rename, you need to press <kbd>X</kbd>. These instructions for uploading are displayed in the tooltip whenever you hover over the item.

[image: Upload and Rename Options]

---

**Units**

You get units for uploading each discovery you make (~200 Unit I believe). Additionally, you appear to get 200 Units immediately for each unique species you discover (and it seems to stack with uploading from the journal). Finally, if you discover all species on a planet (the tooltip on the bottom right when you discover tells you how many are left, or you can see it as `????` in the journal) you apparently get a further bonus (~100k Units - Unverified by myself).

Comment: Actually, in my experience, you don't have to keep the creature/plant in view through the completion of scanner analysis, you just need to keep the scanner active. Once it begins analyzing, you can turn around or move so that something blocks your view of the target, but as long as you keep the button held down, it will still complete.

Comment: @DanHenderson I've found that too in most cases, but I've found for flying creatures it's not always been the case. I thought starting from a holding viewpoint would give a higher chance of success to new players.

Comment: Ah, well I've definitely had a lot of trouble getting the scan to *start* on a flying creature (in fact, with the exception of the "flying fish/snake" type creatures, and a flock of bat-like creatures I once found flying along the ground at walking speed, I've never gotten a scan to start analyzing without killing one and scanning its corpse).

Comment: It's 500 to 5000 units per discovery when you upload, depending on what it is. Plants are on the low end and systems are on the high end. The bonus for scanning everything is 25000 per animal.